# Efficiently move many small files to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I have around 60,000 small image files (total size 200mb) that I would like to move out of my project repository to Amazon S3.

I have tried s3fs (http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/), mounting S3 via Transmit on Mac OS X as well as the Amazon AWS S3 web uploader. Unfortunately it seems like all of these would take a very long time, more than a day or two, to accomplish the task.

Is there any better way?

Comment: Have you tried a client which does multipart uploads? It might just be that many files can be uploaded in one single request. Also see: http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/11/amazon-s3-multipart-upload.html

Comment: Did you increase the number of simultaneous transfers in Transmit? (Preferences -> Transfers -> Transfer up to __ file simultaneously) If you have 'enough' local bandwidth try setting to 100.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few things that could be limiting the flow of data and each has a different way to alleviate it:

1. Your transfer application might be adding overhead.  If s3fs is too slow, you might try other options like the S3 tab on the AWS console or a tool like s3cmd.
2. The network latency between your computer and S3 and the latency in API call responses can be a serious factor in how much you can do in a single thread.  The key to solving this is to upload multiple files (dozens) in parallel.
3. You could just have a slow network connection between you and S3, placing a limit on the total data transfer speed possible.  If you can compress the files, you could upload them in compressed form to a temporary EC2 instance and then uncompress and upload from the instance to S3.

My bet is on number 2 which is not always the easiest to solve unless you have upload tools that will parallelize for you.

Comment: Parallel calls to the API did the trick for me. 2k files (~106mb) in < 10 seconds.. Where is was taking 20 mins or longer in a single thread.

Comment: I ran 50 concurrent apache instances via PHP to achieve those speeds, checking against temporary local files as to not download duplicates on a 1gbit burstable line.

Answer (score 2):

Jeff Atwood made a blog post a few years ago titled [Using Amazon S3 as an Image Hosting Service](https://blog.codinghorror.com/using-amazon-s3-as-an-image-hosting-service/). His solution for a similar problem (image hosting usually consists of hosting many small files) was to use [S3Fox Organizer for Firefox](http://www.rjonna.com/ext/s3fox.php).

To address a previous answer, Amazon S3 does not allow you to unzip your files (to do this you would need to download, unzip, and re-upload).

Comment: Link is dead, seems the plugin is gone

Answer (score 2):

We created a tool for our project with similar requirements.
You can download it here:

https://github.com/mshytikov/s3files

Answer (score 2):

I ran across this thread because I had the same question.  For me, I was uploading about 26,000 small (~50KB each) files via the S3 Management Console web interface, and the throughput got consistently stuck at around 84 KB/s.  I downloaded the AWS CLI, and used the S3 copy command and got about 4MB/s upload throughput.

Here are some references:

- [AWS S3 Manual](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/index.html)
- [Configuring AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html) (Pay attention to the configuring credentials)
- [AWS CLI Installation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html)

After you install the AWS cli, configure it with your access and secret keys:

`aws configure`

Then, S3 copy is pretty straightforward.  See the reference for more examples, but for me it was something like this:

`aws s3 cp images s3://my-bucket/images --recursive`